# Sort 2D array by alphanumeric values like 1, 1b, 1x, 3, 2a, 1c

Tags: php, sorting

I have a array like the following:

```
$array = [
    ['id'=>1, 'name'=>1],
    ['id'=>2, 'name'=>2],
    ['id'=>3, 'name'=>1b],
    ['id'=>4, 'name'=>1a],
    ['id'=>5, 'name'=>4],
    ['id'=>6, 'name'=>7],
];
```

I am trying to sort it so the output is

```
$array = [
    ['id'=>1, 'name'=>1],
    ['id'=>4, 'name'=>1a],
    ['id'=>3, 'name'=>1b],
    ['id'=>2, 'name'=>2],
    ['id'=>5, 'name'=>4],
    ['id'=>6, 'name'=>7],
];
```

I have tried to use the following but it is only sorting by numeric not alphabetically.

```
usort($plots, function($a, $b) {
    return preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','', $a->getPlotNumber()) > preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','', $b->getPlotNumber());
});
```

---

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think the following function is what you're looking for https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php

Comment: How does `$a->getPlotNumber()` relate to the array you have posted?

Comment: Note that the comparison callback for sort functions should return an integer less than or greater than zero, not a boolean. Your function technically produces undefined results, because it will all instances where it returns false will be treated as "should be considered equal".

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit weird - you are sorting an array of associative arrays, but your sort function calls some ->getPlotNumber() which clearly do not exist on your input array.

However it seems like you are looking for this:

```php
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
  return strnatcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
});
```